# JavaScript: checked "true" won't change display to block, as it is stated to do in the function (closed)

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble getting this to work.
The idea is that when the #menuBtn is clicked (checkbox is true) it should change the display of the #menuOverlay to block instead of none. I've checked it out while using a visible checkbox, and it works just as it should when clicking the label icons (turning true/false), but it won´t change the display from none to block on true no matter what I do. Is there anyone that have any advice to what I am doing wrong?

Html:

```
<div class="menu_overlay" id="menuOverlay">
    <label for="menuBtn">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </label>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-text active">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-text">Illustrations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-text">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-text">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

  <div class="container-outer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="brandmark">Logo</div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="menuBtn">
      <div class="landing_page">
        <div class="menu">
                  <label for="menuBtn">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

css (scss):

```
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: white;
    width: 100vw;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }


  /* MENU */
  
  .container-outer {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
  }

  .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 90%;
      height: 6vh;
      position: relative;
  }

  .menu_overlay {
    z-index: 100;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    
    ul { 
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: right;
        margin: 75px 0 0 0;
        padding: 0 2% 0 0;
        }

    .fas {
        text-align: right;
        right: 25px;
        top: 25px;
        position: absolute;
    }
}


  .landing-page {
    max-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .menu-text { // This is for the fonts inside the menu pop up
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .menu_overlay a:hover { // This is for the fonts inside the menu to fill black on hover 
    color: black;
  }

  .fas { // This is for the hamburger menu icon 
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
  }

  .fas:hover { // This is for hover effect on the hambuger menu icon 
      transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  .active { // Active page filled with black in menu overlay 
      color: black;
  }

  #menuBtn {
    display: none; // 
  }
  
  #menuBtn:checked ~ .menu_overlay {
    display: block;
  }


  #menuOverlay {
    display: none;
  }
  
  
  .brandmark {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 101;
  }
```

JS

```
 var x = document.getElementById("menuBtn")
 var menu = document.getElementsById("menuOverlay")
 if (x = true) {
   menu.style.display = "block";
   console.log('this is if');
 } else {
   menu.style.display = "none";
   console.log('this is else');
 }
}
```

Comment: Your JavaScript only runs when the page loads, not every time the checkbox is modified. Put it into an event listener.

Comment: `var menu = document.getElementsById("menuOverlay")` getElementsById does not exist.

Comment: Open your dev tools, look at the console, and then fix any errors it reports first. Because as James points out: that function doesn't exist, and will be a nice long red piece of error text. That said, there's so much more wrong here. `if (x = true)` is an assignment, not a comparison. `var` is from a bygone era (use `let` or `const`), you're directly manipulating `.style` instead of using `.classList` to toggle classes and keeping CSS itself in your CSS file, you're using `<a>` as a button (so... use a `<button>`) and worse, you use `<a href="#">`, i.e. "navigate to top" under HTML5 rules...

Comment: Thanks James, didn't notice the typo.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that helped and it is now resolved!

Answer (score 0):

getElementById no getElementsById

```
var x = document.getElementById("menuBtn")
var menu = document.getElementById("menuOverlay")
```